# In HTML how to auto resize the image in a fixed size div based on how many pictures are present in that div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that, I made a fixed sized div and I want to fit images in that div according to how many picture are present in that.

I want suppose if I put a single image in div it will fit at full size of div and if I put 5 or 6 images, so images should resize self to adjust in that fixed div. How to do that ?

Comment: You might want to add some actual code to show that you at least tried something or have some ideas.  i.e.  What are the constraints on your div (width / height).  How do they need to be displayed (all in one row or in multiple rows, etc.).  A lot of frameworks (e.g. bootstrap) and just CSS can take care of some of that automatically for you.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you require - for example do the images have the same natural dimensions/aspect-ratio, what do you mean by 'fill' - are you looking for some sort of masonry layout, perhaps with some images being able to be shown only partially so that the space is truly filled, or is it important that the whole of each image is shown etc

Answer (score 0):

For an answer closer to what you need I would need more information or code. I have suposed that you have a div with fixed width and inside variable amount of imgs. I hope this helps :)

```css
#container{
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#container img{
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg" >
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg" >
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg" >
</div>
```